# How to block Ports in Windows Firewall via GPO to Windows XP Machines?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-xp, firewall, group-policy

How can I block certain ports for outbound communication for a set of Computers running Windows XP when joined in a Microsoft AD Domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Windows XP firewall only blocks incoming traffic.  It does not monitor outbound traffic. for that functioality you would need to upgrade to windows 7.  By default windows 7 also allows all outbound traffic but you can create a GPO that will turn on blocking all outbound traffic unless there is a rule to permit the traffic.

Comment: I know that Win7 (and Vista) can do that via GPO because they have a higher version of the firewall.. just needed to know if there is any way to do it via GPO to XP Machines :\